# disable the webview when sliding menu is open in android

Tags: android, webview, blur, slidingmenu

I am using a sliding menu over a webview.
I need to disable or blur the webview when the menu is open.
On adding a framelayout and setting foreground, the webview can be blurred but is not disabled and is still scrollable/clickable.
How can I completely freeze the view beneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add enable or disable clicks to the webview by setting the view that is overlayed on top to either be clickable or not clickable.

You can try creating a method like the one below of use the `setClickable()` method in another similar fashion.

```
public void setClickable(boolean isClickable){
     blurView.setClickable(isClickable);
}
```

While your overlay is clickable it will intercept all touch events and the user will not be able to interact with the webview.

Note you can set the default behavior for a view easily in xml as well by using this line

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: How can I create a transparent view over the webview  without changing the visibility of the webview behind? on placing a view over webview i am having to make the webview's visibility to gone, which i do not want to do.I want the webview to be seen behind but not clickable

Comment: I used a transparent background color of #88676767 and the above solution works :)